# Tensor Algebra of Symmetric Algebra with Symoblic Tensors

Tags: symbolic, tensors

Given
$V=\mathbb{R}^3,$
I would like to work symbolically with elements of
$\mathrm{T}^{(k_1,\dotsc,k_n)}(\mathrm{S} V),$
i.e. vectors of the form

$$\phi = \phi_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \phi_n$$

with
$\phi_i \in \mathrm{S}^{k_i}V$
and
$\mathrm{S}^{k_i}V$
being the $k_i$-fold symmetric tensor power of $V$.

I would like to implement this by defining appropriate domains that can be used as assumptions.
I can clearly use

```
Arrays[Table[d, k], Reals, Symmetric[All]]
```

as a domain for $\mathrm{S}^{k}V$, but how can I construct a domain for $T^{(k_1,\dotsc,k_n)}(\mathrm{S} V)$?